# Different errors after compiling java file to kotlin using Android Studio

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin

I use Flutter and I don't know too much about Java/Kotlin. Some Flutter projects support Kotlin so files like MainActivity is a .kt which changes a bit from the original java one.

I had to load an SDK that calls methods from a .java that I need to convert.

I tried on a Flutter project that doesn't support Kotlin and everything works but when I imported this file to my Flutter-Kotlin project I had to convert it (there is a conversion option in Android Studio) and apparently this conversion is not correct.

For example this:

```
@Override
    fun ...
```

is not converted to anything at all when it should be:

```
override fun ...
```

The thing is that I get other errors like:

> Smart cast to 'MethodChannel' is impossible, because 'channel' is a
> mutable property that could have been changed by this time

```
channel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(
                object : MethodCallHandler() {
                    override
```

(converted Kotlin)

Is there an easy way to convert to Kotlin without being familiar to either Kotlin or Java?

Another option would be not support Java in my Flutter project but that would give me other headaches.